# Conversion in template from Classes inherit a base class to base

Tags: c++

I have node that is a template with link list. I want to create in my restaurant project a list of item use node like linked list with reference counter, special inherit beverage and edible. A bevrage and edible inherit from item.
I have a menu that have dishes include all this three class and I need to change or add dish with my manager. I get a problem because I can't convert the class to the base from `node<Item>*`.

I want to use function `addNewtItem()`;

```
#ifndef MENUE_H
#define MENUE_H
#include "Node.h"

class Menue
{
    public:
        Menue();
        Node<Item>* _head;

        void deleteItem(Node<Item>* item);
        Node<Item>* getItem(int i);

        void addNewtItem(Node<Item>&  nextNode)   {if(_head)    _head->addNode(nextNode);   else _head=nextNode;}

        void printMenue();
        void deleteItem(int i);

        ~Menue();

    protected:

    private:
};

#endif // MENUE_H
```

call from this class

```
#ifndef MENEGER_H
#define MENEGER_H
#include "Node.h"
#include "Waiter.h"
#include "Menue.h"
class Meneger: public Waiter
{
    public:

        Meneger();
        ~Meneger();
        void editItem (Node<Edible>&     newItem){  _myMenue->addNewtItem(newItem);}
        void editItem (Node<Special>&    newItem){  _myMenue->addNewtItem(newItem);}
        void editItem (Node<Beverage>&   newItem){  _myMenue->addNewtItem(newItem);}
    protected:

    private:
         int _amountTable;
        int _weiterId;
        Table* _table;
        Menue*  _myMenue;
};

#endif // MENEGER_H
```

this is the node class with the link list

I want to use this function `operator  Node<newType>()`  but the conversion doesn't work

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
#include "Item.h"
#include "Edible.h"
#include "Beverage.h"
#include "Special.h"

template <class T>
class Node
{
    public:

        T* _item;
        Node* _next;
        int _refCount;
        Node():_next(NULL),_refCount(0),_item(NULL){}
        Node(T* item=0,Node<T>* next=0):_next(next),_item(item),_refCount(1){}
        ~Node(){    if(_item)delete _item;_item=NULL;}
        T& operator* (){return *_item;}
        T* operator-> (){return _item;}
        void addRefCount()  {_refCount++;}
        void addNode(Node<T>* newItem);
        int removeItem(){return --_refCount;}
        template<class newType> // template function for
        operator  Node<newType>() // implicit conversion ops.
        {
            return Node<newType>(_item);
        }

    private:
};


template <class T>
inline void Node<T>::addNode(Node<T>* newItem)
{
    if(newItem==NULL)
        return;
   newItem->_next=_next;
   _next=newItem;

}



#endif // NODE_H
```

Comment: Is there JavaScript in this question?

Comment: What is the problem ? "Doesn't work" isn't enough to help you : Is there a compiler error message ? an inappropriate behavior during runtime ? if so, what is desired behavior and behavior you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the problem you're looking for but... it's a problem.

Look at the method `Menue::addNewItem()`

```
    void addNewtItem(Node<Item>&  nextNode)   {if(_head)    _head->addNode(nextNode);   else _head=nextNode;}
```

I don't know what is an `Item` but `_head` is a pointer to a `Node<Item>`. And `Node::addNode()` receive a `Node<T>` (`Node<Item>`, in this case) pointer. But `nextNode` is a reference to a `Node<Item>`, not a pointer to a `Node<Item>`

So, when you write

```
_head->addNode(nextNode);
```

you're trying to pass a `Node<Item>` to a method that expect a **pointer** to a `Node<Item>`; and when you write

```
_head = nextNode;
```

you're trying to assign a `Node<Item>` to a variable of type **pointer** to a `Node<Item>`.

Your intention was

```
_head->addNode(&nextNode);
_head = & nextNode;
```

?